# How to align a large glyph left in a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to make a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: xx-large"></span>
    Buy Now<br/>
    <span class="small">Instant and secure</span><br/>
</a>
```

The glyph is, as I intend, large. But I want the two lines of text to both push to the left to make room for the glyph.

What I get currently is this:

[image]

What I'm aiming for is this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pull-left` in the icon, and change the `btn` to `text-align:left`:

CSS

```
.btn-lg {
  text-align:left;
  width:190px;
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart pull-left" style="font-size:xx-large;margin:5px;"></span> 
    Buy Now<br>
    <small>Instant and secure</small>
</a>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/86858